# Build failing due to multiple Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I had Xcode wit iOS8.4 but i then installed iOS9 . I downloaded Xcode_7_GM_Release dmg file which had iOS9 sdk.
Then, I renamed the already exiting /Applications/Xcode.app to /Application/Ycode.app and installed the downloaded dmg file.
I built my source code w.r.t to new Xcode.app having iOS9. 
Now i launched the Xcode tool and copied the libs of my code to the app in Xcode .
On building, i get the below error.

```
     ld: warning: object file  (/Users/smuser/app/__**______libs/smclient.a(smclientdaemon.o)) was built           for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (7.0)
ld: '/Users/smuser/app/-***----libs/smclient.a(smclientdaemon.o)' does     not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcodesetting  ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable     bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see  invocation)
```

Please could anybody tell me the the reason for it ? 
Do i need to update the Xcode tool from app store?? Or the target phone needs to have iOS9 ??

Comment: B I T C O D E.  Google it.

Comment: Bitcode message is not my question .But,the other message  "was built           for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (7.0)" . I am confused as to what should i update , my Xcode tool, Phone target ??

Answer (score 1):

Project -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode set this to "No". "Yes" is set by default.

This worked with Xcode 7.0 from the app store and iOS9 installed on target device.

If this doesn't work I would recommend downloading Xcode 7.0 from the App Store and trying the above steps again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But could please also suggest on the other message ""was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (7.0)" . I am confused as to what should i update , my Xcode tool, Phone target ?? – "

Comment: It may be that one of your libs is linked to an older version of iOS.. (7.0) maybe? As suggested above - look into Xcode from the App Store. At least that way, you can trust where the update came from.